# Formatting and calculations in XSL

Tags: xml, math, xslt, format

I've got got this  DataView that is using XSL. One columns is a link.  The field I'm using as query string key {@Title} needs to be changed for the link.

- Its currently 9 digits and I need to drop the first digit.
- The remaining 8 numbers need to be muliplied by 8

so N00000010 turns into 00000080

the below code is just outputing

https://myserver.edu/zzz/r.aspx?key=N00000010

but should be

https://myserver.edu/zzz/r.aspx?key=00000080

UPDATE: If overflow, output can me more that 8 digits if need be and actually, this is acceptable and even preferable.

https://myserver.edu/zzz/r.aspx?key=80

```
    <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Supervisor" /></td><td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@StartingSickBalance, '#,##0.00;-#,##0.00')" /></td><td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@FiscalStartingBalance, '#,##0.00;-#,##0.00')" /></td><td class="ms-vb">
            <a href="https://myserver.edu/zzz/r.aspx?key={@Title}">See Balances</a>
            </td><td class="ms-vb">
```

Comment: I'm getting broken links when I try to see your output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came to a very similar solution as dash, only I have used format-number() with the format specifier '0' instead of concat().

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(substring({@Title}, 2,8))*8, '00000000')" />
```

It worked for me in VS2010.

Comment: I tried that and it just wouldn't work for me. However, I agree, if the poster's parser works with it, it's the simplest way to do it. +1

Comment: +1 - No need to use an `xsl:value-of` though and you can drop `format-number()` based on the OPs update. Just do `<a href="https://myserver.edu/zzz/r.aspx?key={number(substring(@Title,2))*8}">See Balances</a>`

Comment: Very elegant. Dash, thank you so much for your analysis. Not sure why i had noob issues placing your xsl:value code in that <td> for some reason. Sorry about the confusion on requirements.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

If there is no need to restrict the output with leading 0's, then the following should work:

```
  <xsl:variable name="linkId" select="number(substring({@Title}, 2,8)) * 8" />
  <a href="https://myserver.edu/zzz/r.aspx?key={$linkId}">Test</a>
```

Or, as @DevNull mentions, without the variable:

```
<a href="https://myserver.edu/zzz/r.aspx?key={number(substring(@Title, 2,8)) * 8}">Test</a>
```

This would produce the output:

```
<a href="https://myserver.edu/zzz/r.aspx?key=80">Test</a>
```

**Earlier Answer**

One way to do this is to substring your original string to remove the leading letter:

```
substring({@Title}, 2, 8)
```

This gives us: `00000010`

We then place a 1 at the front to maintain the leading 0's:

```
concat(1, substring({@Title}, 2, 8))
```

giving: `100000010`

We can then convert to a number and multiply this by 8:

```
number(concat(1, substring({@Title}, 2, 8))) * 8
```

giving `800000080`

Then substring again:

```
substring(number(concat(1, substring({@Title}, 2, 8))) * 8, 2, 8)
```

to give: `00000080`

Putting it all together:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(number(concat(1, substring({@Title}, 2, 8))) * 8, 2, 8)" />
```

To use it in the output:

```
  <xsl:variable name="linkId" select="substring(number(concat(1, substring({@Title}, 2, 8))) * 8, 2, 8)" />
  <a href="https://myserver.edu/zzz/r.aspx?key={$linkId}">Test</a>
```

Seems a bit long winded, but works. I couldn't get `format-number` to maintain the leading zero's in my xsl parser (C#, .Net 4.0)

If `format-number` works for you then the following is more elegant:

```
  <xsl:variable name="linkId" select="format-number(number(concat(1, substring({@Title}, 2, 8))) * 8, '00000000')" />
  <a href="https://myserver.edu/zzz/r.aspx?key={$linkId}">Test</a>
```

However, as @MvG points out, 8 digits could become 9 if your multiply by 8 overflows the original 8 digits.

Comment: You run into trouble when the multiplication increases the number of digits: 201 will be turned via 1201 and 9608 into 608, where 1608 would have been more correct. So perhaps you want to do a case distinction: multiply your way if there is a leading 0, or multiply without that extra 1 otherwise. Of course, OP doesn't indicate that overflow could actually happen, or what should be done if it does. So no need to change the answer if we can be sure of a leading 0.

Comment: @MvG - very true. I naively assumed they would always be `1's`!

Comment: Sorry, output can be as many digits as needed and sorry, can be less than 8, so key=80 is fine actually. will update questions.

Comment: @cyberpine; in which case, just drop the format-number and concat parts. See update.

Comment: +1 for everything after **UPDATE:**. You could also not use an `xsl:variable` and just put your select directly in the href attr: `<a href="https://myserver.edu/zzz/r.aspx?key={number(substring(@Title, 2,8)) * 8}">Test</a>`